# Python: use multiprocessing in a while loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Okay so I am implementing the famous Conway's Game of Life in Python, and in order to speed things up, I am trying to use some multiprocessing.

So far, this is what I have (I can provide more code if needed) :

```py
grid: Grid = Grid(grid_size)

grid_array: np.ndarray = grid.grid_init(initialization.value)

living_cells: set[tuple] = find_living_cells(grid_array)
living_cells_subsets = _create_subsets(living_cells, jobs)

while grid_array.any():
    args = [
        (
            grid_array,
            subset
        )
        for subset in living_cells_subsets
    ]

    with Pool(jobs) as pool:
        result = pool.starmap(update_positions, args)
    pool.join()

    living_cells = set()
        prev_living_cells = set()
        for res in result:
            living_cells.update(res[0])
            prev_living_cells.update(res[1])

        grid_array = update_grid(grid_array, living_cells, prev_living_cells)

        living_cells_subsets = _create_subsets(living_cells, jobs)
```

This is working well, except that it is taking too (way) long to instantiate the processes at each while loop.
What can I do to avoid this behavior ? I read about `Queue` and `Process` but couldn't find how to make it works properly and with a clean code.

I didn't find any good answers online but I may have missed some, so this may be a duplicated topic.

Comment: This is not a good candidate for multiprocessing.  Each process has a very tiny amount work to do.  The overhead of launching a new process, starting up a new Python interpreter and restoring its state is going to vastly overwhelm the tiny time required to update the colony state.  The generations all have to be serialized, and unless you have the subsets overlap, you aren't getting accurate numbers.

Comment: When each process gets its job to do, that includes the contents of `grid_array`. That ends up pickling one copy of the grid per job, which uses lots of CPU and RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the replies ! So even for large grids, using multiprocessing won't be useful ? Then how can I speed things up (except by optimising the calculus part) when having a large grid size ?

Comment: For starters I would create the pool prior to the `while not grid_array.any():` loop instead of creating and destroying pool processes over and over. And how does this loop terminate? `grid_any` is not modified in what you have posted. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Booboo I edited my post so you can see the rest of the loop. And the thing is that I don't know how to create the pool outside of my loop and use it inside it. And I do need multiprocessing when the grid becomes too big.

Comment: Stepping back, how is performance ever going to be an issue for this task?  How large are your grids?  You can switch to numpy and use a 3x3 convolution to collect the neighbors counts, but unless you're doing a 10k x 10k grid and running hundreds of thousands of generations, is it really worth the trouble?

Comment: Well it gets quite slow with a 1k x 1k grid. I know it's quite useless because we can't see much, but I am training myself with Python and thought I could try to learn how to use multiprocessing, but if it's not worth it/useless I should probably try to optimise my code first

Comment: I see you're mentionning 3x3 convolution with numpy (which I am using), how can I do that ? Because for now I am getting the neighbors with for loops, it runs quite fast but isn't optimum I agree

Comment: @Raphaellndr This [demo](https://ideone.com/zg87GZ) is what I meant concerning creating the pool outside a `while` loop and using it inside.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the demo ! Really helpful, I will try this asap !